# How to focus to text input without using ref?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have try using focus and also autofocus.Using React Native 0.43
Example simple scenario

```
<ListItem
 title="Username"
 textInput={true}
 textInputValue={this.state.userName}
 textInputSecureTextEntry={false}
 textInputOnChangeText={this
 .bindData
 .bind(this, 'userName')}
 textInputAutoFocus={this.state.userNameAutoFocus}
 textInputFocus={this.state.userNameFocus}
 textInputKeyboardType="default"
 textInputPlaceHolder="Type your Username Here"
 textInputContainerStyle={styles.inputFormStyle}
 textInputOnSubmitEditing={this
 .nextFormComponent
 .bind(this, 'userPassword')}
 textInputReturnKeyType="next" />
```

[Source Code](https://pastebin.com/Tw67PjjP)
[Source Code NPM](https://pastebin.com/iWDNUnWs)

Comment: Please edit your question, adding the code section in which you have a problem. No one can help you when you add a link for 300 code lines without specifiying exactly what the problem is.

Comment: added more simple code to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    textInputFocus:true
  };
}

render() {
 <View>
   <TextInput autoFocus={this.state.textInputFocus} />
 </View>
}
```

try this code.

Comment: My original code using same as above and not working.   `<ListItem
            
            textInputAutoFocus={this.state.userNameAutoFocus}
            textInputFocus={this.state.userNameFocus}
            textInputReturnKeyType="next"></ListItem>`

Answer (score 0):

You Can try that :

```
class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.nameInput.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <input defaultValue="Won't focus"/>
        <input ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }}   defaultValue="will focus"  />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to changed npm source file. The problem start when i put ref at source npm it will saying  error stateless function shouldn't have refs.Above maybe the last choice for me write back the npm source file like above.